# Snort: users are not able to login when Wordpress Login Bruteforcing rule is on

Tags: php, wordpress, snort

I got this wordpress login bruteforcing rule from https://rules.emergingthreats.net/open/snort-2.9.0/rules/emerging-web_server.rules

> alert tcp $EXTERNAL_NET any -> $HTTP_SERVERS $HTTP_PORTS (msg:"ET
>   WEB_SERVER Wordpress Login Bruteforcing Detected";
>   flow:to_server,established; content:"/wp-login.php"; nocase;
>   fast_pattern; http_uri; content:"POST"; http_method;
>   content:"log|3d|"; http_client_body; content:"pwd|3d|";
>   http_client_body; threshold: type both, track by_src, count 5, seconds
>   60; classtype:attempted-recon; sid:2014020; rev:3;)

When I change it from 'alert' to 'reject', I am not able to login. (It says connection is reset) I don't quite understand what the rule means. (what I understand is when logging, it looks for log or 3d in post/get method. Look for client_body pwd 3d. attempted-recon means, it's someone "probing" the server)

Only one user is able to login to wordpress, when the 'reject' is used. Three other users has `"ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"` in Chrome.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question. You might have better luck on superuser (or maybe serverfault).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule is likely not written very well so you are getting false positives on legitimate log ins. The rule probably needs to be revised so that it does not block legitimate log in attempts or you should leave it as alert and just investigate each to alert to see it was a recon attempt or not.

To clarify what this rule is looking for:

content:"/wp-login.php"; nocase; fast_pattern; http_uri;

This is looking for the login page in the uri, i.e. "http://example.com/wp-login.php"

content:"POST"; http_method;

This is looking for the POST method, so it would be a post request to something like the above URL.

content:"log|3d|"; http_client_body;

This is not, as you suggested, looking for the content "log" or 3d, when you you vertical pipes in snort content rules it means that it is looking for the hex value of what is inside the vertical pipes. This is actually looking for the content "log=" as 3d is "=" when converted from hex to ascii. You can use a [site like this one](http://www.asciitohex.com/) to convert hex to ascii. So this is essentially looking for a variable in the http client body called "log".

content:"pwd|3d|"; http_client_body;

This is looking for the content "pwd=" within the client body.

The threshold is depreciated and should not be used (detection_filter should be used instead) but it is just going to determine when to generate an alert.

The rule is likely trying to look for someone who is trying to get information about where logs are stored for the server as "pwd" typically refers to "print working directory" and log would be the log file, so I'm guessing there is some sort of exploit in wordpress that allows someone to send a crafted request and the server will return its current directory and a file it's logging to or something like that.

This content or request may be common for certain wordpress servers so you would likely want to modify this rule so it's not looking for content that is also going to be in legitimate requests.

When you change this to reject snort is sending a reset packet when this rule alerts, which is why clients are getting a reset message in chrome.